# Fail to Add Migration in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: nuget-package, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to add migrations from existing Models in my **ASP.NET Core 1.0** web app.

When I type `Add-Migration`  I get the following result. I use VS 2015 Community and the Nuget Package Manager Console to execute the commands on Windows 7. Previously I upgraded the PowerShell (from version 2.0 to version 4.0). I cannot understand this error so if someone can explain what happens I would really appreciate.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.
PM> Add-Migration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: InitMigration
The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
```

Answer (score 0):

For EF Core, you enable migrations with the add-migration command (as the messages pretty clearly indicate :)). Try `add-migration -Name InitMigration`

See here for more:https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/powershell.html#add-migration

Comment: So were you using EF 6 or core? Must be 6 if that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

> Upgrade to PowerShell 5.0